# TF400898 error after upgrading to TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, upgrade, tfs-2015

After upgrading TFS Express 2013 to 2015 I get the following error(s):

1) When trying to go to the tfs admin page

```
TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred.
```

2) In the event log:

```
Web Request Details
    Url: http://tfs.XXXXXX.com:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 14.0.23102.0, Pro, SKU:31)
    Headers: not available
    Path: /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx
    Local Request: False
    Host Address: 76.XXX.XXX.115
    User: RR2014\sweaver [authentication type: NTLM]

Exception Message: The extension '.svc' is not registered with WCF/WF handler. Please either remove relativeAddress '~/ServiceManagement.svc' in 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations' from configuration file or register the corresponding extension '.svc' with WCF/WF handler. Please refer to 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx' for how to register an extension in IIS. (type ConfigurationErrorsException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.NormalizedRelativeAddress(String relativeAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.LoadConfigParameters()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager..ctor()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.OnEnsureInitialized(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.SafeEnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.BeginProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

3) In Visual Studio 2015 when trying to connect :

```
CData elements not valid at top level of an XML document. Line 1, position 3.
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The only resource I could find related to this issue is an [MSDN forums post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/723db5cf-f754-431f-b938-2634d0b5ac12/fresh-tfs-2015-rc-install-tf400898-an-internal-error-occurred?forum=tfsgeneral).

> I suspect that you tried to install Windows Server AppFabric, but have
>   not configured it. If you are not using Windows Server AppFabric, you
>   should uninstall/unconfigure it.

This comment was enlightening, but a little scary since I actually rely on AppFabric !!!

I am only however using the caching functionality and it turns out AppFabric has a whole `Service Management Service` that intercepts requests - or [something to that effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383422%28v=azure.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I wasn't using that.

I was able therefore to just uninstall the hosting components to fix the issue.

- Go Start > `Programs and Features`
- Select `AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server` and click `Change`
- Deselect the `Hosting Services`

[image]

- Continue with `Next` to remove this component.
- You should now be able to run TFS without conflict with AppFabric.

If you're actually using the `Hosting Services` you probably already know more than I do about how it works so I hope you can take it from there to diagnose the problem. The original error message should give some direction then.

Comment: Wow.  You saved Friday afternoon.